# How do I clear the update ready status for a Mac app store update I don't want?

Tags: mac, osx-lion

For example I updated xcode after the Lion OS X update came out, and now there is a new version where the only difference is a warning at the start to quit itunes.

Clearly I don't need to install the update, so how do I clear it from the updates in the app store on the Mac? It's distracting.

Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the "Install Xcode.app" file would get rid of it. But then, you'll need to download the whole 3GB file again when there is an update you want. If there's another way, I'd like to know as well.

I wish Apple would just go back to putting the Xcode releases on the web for free public download. They really don't work all that well with the App Store, the 3GB installer takes up a good portion of an SSD, and the people interested in Xcode aren't going to mind having to go to a website to get it.

Comment: Rats,  I was hoping there was a solution that didn't involve that. I'll have to ignore it until the next xcode update otherwise.